# Version error of torchvision dependency when installing medcat via pip

Tags: python, pip, package, torchvision

When I attempt to install medcat via

```
pip install medcat
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision~=0.8.0 (from medcat) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.5.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision~=0.8.0 (from medcat)
```

To me, this would imply that there is no torchvision version 0.8.0.

How do I get around this issue when installing the medcat package?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by installing medcat via:

```
pip install --upgrade medcat -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```